# How to lock on to a cloned form in Delphi?

Tags: forms, delphi, chat, delphi-xe2

I am writing a chat program that has a bunch of clients connect to it and populate themselfs to a listview, I want to be able to click on each individual client and open up a form that looks like a chat, but I want to be able to do it to multiple clients at the same time.

I have made `Form2` (the chat window) clone itself for every instance, however I need to know how to lock on to the cloned form to make changes such as `Form2.RichEdit.Lines.Add`

However when I try to do this it does not work because I'm not locking on to the right form since it is cloned I am assuming it is no longer `Form2`

Any info on this would be highly appreciated.

---

**Update**

I am going to go ahead a reword what I am trying to do.

I will explain what im trying to do: I have a chat program (server) that is listening for clients to connect via Indy10 sockets When the client connects it populates the ListView with the user name and when I click on the user name (the server) opens privatemessageform where I can chat with the client.

I want to be able to have multiple clients connected and I want to be able to click on as many as I want and have it clone the privatemessageform and have 2 separate chat windows to 2 separate clients

The problem is: When trying to click on the seccond user the program gets confused and cannot lock on to that seccond user's privatemessageform (clone).

And if any more info is needed and I mean anything at all please do not hesitate to ask I will be on for several hours and constantly checking this thread.

I've been stuck on this for 3 days so I would really love to get this resolved and move forward with my project. Any information is highly appreciated. **Thanks in advance!**

Comment: What do you mean "clone itself"? Show the essential code, and what fails.

Comment: Im About to go to bed, i will post the code tomorrow, thanks for the reply though.

Answer (score 4):

Open  Project Options and remove Form2 from auto-creation list. Do not use that variable any more.

Rename `TForm2` to some meaningful name. Once you would have ~10 forms in your program you would forget what you meant by numbers 2, 5, 7 ...
ALWAYS give variables meaningful names, that includes components, that includes forms. Here i will name `TForm2` a `TPrivMessageForm`

Use a special array of variables to keep several forms, not a single global variable. For example like that:

```
Type TChatUser = string; 
// to begin with, user is a name. Then it may become URL, or GUID or something    
// complex like `record` or `class` or whatever

Type TPMForms = TDictionary<TChatUser, TPrivMessageForm>; 

PMForms := TPMForms.Create;
```

Creating new private message window after clicked on user:

```
if not PMForms.ContainsKey(ClickedUser) 
   then PMForms.Add(ClickedUser, TPrivMessageForm.Create(Application) );
PMForms[ClickedUser].ChatWith := ClickedUser; // variable in ex-TForm2 to tell several instances apart
```

When such form is closed - it should via its `OnClose`

- Remove itself from `PMForms` list (so no dangling pointers would remain)
- chose `caRelease` for closing actions (making VCL actually free the form object)

See Also

- http://delphi.about.com/od/beginners/a/using-t-dictionary-hash-tables-in-delphi.htm
- http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/XE4/en/Generics_Collections_TDictionary_(Delphi)

PS. Edit your question please and add TAG with your specific Delphi version.

PPS. download ready-made FLOSS chat programs and just read and learn how they do it. Maybe instead of opening a free-floating (cluttering desktop) form you'd better open Tab in `PageControl`. "Use the Source, Luke"

- https://sourceforge.net/p/dreamchat/wiki/Home/
- https://sourceforge.net/p/achat/wiki/Home/
- http://www.visualirc.net/features.php

*For the latter to find the sources one has to type two words "Visual IRC" at www.google.com and get http://sourceforge.net/p/visualirc/mercurial/ci/default/tree/ - this crucial information i did omitted in  fair belief that a person **interested** in finding sources would be able to do it on his own.*

PPPS. Those is not "cloned": cloned are separated objects. What you talk is several instances of the same form class. Like you may have two or more labels on the form, you can have two or more forms in your application.

Comment: Thanks for the reply i will try that and then i will submit some code for you all to look at.

Comment: Actually, why do you think we should want to look at your code ;-)
You're making the chat so you can learn from earlier attempts at writing chats. Actually i think you'd rather just take any of those projects and adapt them to your needs, rather than re-inventing the bicycle.

Comment: I am using Delphi XE2, unfortunately i cannot seem to understand how to implement the code you posted, is there any way you can explain it differently? or provide more examples, i have tried this numerous times in different ways, i thought i had it once but it ended up not working so please get back to me asap. Thanks again

Comment: Someone please give me an answer

Comment: "something not work" is not the way programmers speak with computers an with each other. Programmers report certain full error descriptions. http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html
----
And i repeat - you have to implement nothing - everything is implemented years ago, just read the sources of readymade FLOSS chat programs.

Comment: I figured out the issue, the code you gave me is missing several Crucial elements to make it work, things that if i was answering someone else's question i would have included. while i agree with you that "something not work" is not a proper thing to say, you need to understand that when i said that i was directing it to your answer.. your answer does not work, it didnt work for me and it will not work for anybody, simply because your inglish is broken up and you only gave half of the answer making it even more difficult to implement your answer into my program.

Comment: if you are going to answer please make sure you answer actually helps and not create more confusion, i did use tdictionary however your code is extremely flawed and if you werent just answering to boost your numbers then maybe you would have actually tried to help but unfortunately your answer just added to the confusion.

Comment: and yes i looked up the links you posted for me to look at the source for FLOSS chat programs, they were really nice exe's none were source codes buddy. the problem has been resolved but i will not accept your answer because insted of explaining your answer differently as i requested you decided to point out my flaws in the question i asked, im more than glad to provide more info as i mentioned but you never requested it.. sorry to say but im dissapointed to see you are a part of this comunity.

Comment: Well, perhaps VisualIRC from version 2 really decided to close sources, but about two other projects...  Both links lead to the pages, where top-level menu has "Code" button. How you could miss those i cannot understand. Sorry, i am not inclined that my answer misses anything but most basic Pascal knowledge. And yes, i was not righting the whole program for you. I just outlined the overall concept and gave you hints what to google and learn.  And since you "figured out" i guess you finally had to it. Usually i don't give free fish, but a fisher rod instead. U may keep waiting for the fish OTOH

Comment: i was not asking for you to write the program for me.. unfortunately i dont believe you posess the knowledge to do that nor was i asking for free fish.. i asked for you to word your example differently, i asked for you to try and explain, insted what i got was someone who obviously need to learn better grammar and someone who obviously had no intention in helping.. u can take ur fishing rod and shove it buddy..

Comment: sorry, pal, i cannot buy it from a person who cannot find a sources download link on provided URLs, nor can explain WHAT to explain here. If you think i don't understand my example and can not explain this - up to you. Still this answer - bad to your standard - is the only answer here. Perhaps no one else person can catch a fish for you.

Comment: im sorry was that english? can anyone please translate?